# how to know the TCP buffer size dynamically

Tags: winapi, winsock

Is it possible to know the TCP buffer size dynamically on windows.I set the TCP buffer size using SO_SNDBUF,SO_RECVBUF and also can check its allocated buffer size using getsockopt(). But I wanted to know how to get the available buffer size so that if buffer size goes beyond I can take some action.Any utility or api will be equally useful.
My question is specific to windows.Though of anyone knows anything about linux it can also be useful to know for me to get any any parallel.

Comment: actually I am getting socket error 10055 after around 17020 hours of running.This error means that windows don't have sufficient memory for that.I just thought that if I know the buffer capacity of my TCP socket I will disconnect it or will clean it up after sometime.you can refer to my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367872/windows-2003-server-socket-error-10055 for this issues

Comment: How many connections do you create?

Comment: @Eugene Homyakov,There is only one socket connection.But this is connection is heavily(around 5-7 Mbps data exchange) used for transferring the text data.

Comment: I don't think transferring data can trigger this error. It's more likely that you are leaking sockets, i.e. forgetting to call `closesocket`

Comment: @Eugene Homyakov,Even I thought it in the same way.I cross checked my code for the same, but this is not the case.I also saw that even in 20 hours of my testing my connection hardly gets disconnected only 1-2 times.I also used "TCPView"(quite parallel to netstat command) to check the same(immediately after starting the application and then checked it intermittently). It don't show me any increased no. of connections over the period of time.So I just hope that this is something else,.

Comment: 1-2 times per 20 hours is 850-1700 disconnects per 17020 hours, which is enough to cause that in case leak does exist. Are you absolutely sure there is no leak? You can replace all `socket`/`closesocket` calls over all project with custom calls that track number of sockets.

Comment: @Eugene Homyakov, But my program gets killed within 20 hours.showing the error of TCP buffer error(socket error 10055). Also I crosschecked it with the application have.There is no such case of socket memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Buffers are used asynchronously by the kernel. You can not control them. Moreover, the underlying implementation can ignore your SO_SNDBUF/SO_RECVBUF requests, or choose to provide smaller/larger amounts than requested.